# My form moves to the left side of page after clicking asp button to send email. Not supposed to happen

Tags: asp.net, css, forms, vbscript, css-position

I have this css code:

```
form 
{
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#FFFFFF, endColorstr=#6EA5FF);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, bottom, left 175px, from(#CCCCCC), to(#EEEEEE));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
background-color: #E0E0E0;
margin:auto;
position:relative;
width:640px;
height:820px;
font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
line-height: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid #999;
border: inset 1px solid #333;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

for this form:

```
<form  id="form" runat="server">
    <h1 align="center">Ticker Tape Updater</h1>
        <legend>Message (to be appended to current message)</legend>
```

and whenever i click my asp button inside of the form to send an email, the form moves to the left of the screen, which was originally centered. after I send an email I have some code in my vbscript that calls an alert box to pop up saying that the email has been sent.  If I refresh the page I get the email pop up box and the email sends again and the form is still on the left side of the page. If i click an asp button on the page that clears all of the text boxes and resets all of my checkboxes then the form goes back to the middle.  I think since when I refresh the page and get the alert message again and the email sent again, that the code doesn't finish running or something. Any ideas? Here is my vb code:

```
Protected Sub submitBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles submitBtn.Click

    Dim msg As String = "- " + TextBox1.Text + " -"

    If (Checkbox4.Checked = True Or Checkbox5.Checked = True) And (DepartmentIsSelected() = False) Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

        If AtLeastOneIsChecked() = True Then

            'Add message to Screen 1
            If Checkbox1.Checked Then
                UpdateMessage(1, msg)
            End If

            'Add message to Screen 2
            If Checkbox2.Checked Then
                UpdateMessage(2, msg)
            End If

            'Add message to Screen 3
            If Checkbox3.Checked Then
                UpdateMessage(3, msg)
            End If


        End If


        If (Checkbox4.Checked = True Or Checkbox5.Checked = True) And (DepartmentIsSelected() = True) Then

            'Send emails
            If Checkbox4.Checked And DepartmentIsSelected() Then
                SendMessageToEmailOrText("email", msg)
            End If

            'Send texts
            If Checkbox5.Checked And DepartmentIsSelected() Then
                SendMessageToEmailOrText("text", msg)
            End If

        End If

        If AtLeastOneIsChecked() Then
            ClearAll()
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Protected Sub UpdateMessage(ByVal screenNumber As Integer, ByVal message As String)

"code for sub"

End Sub
    Protected Sub SendMessageToEmailOrText(ByVal emailOrText As String, ByVal message As String)
        'This section grabes the email addresses and text address from the function then send out the emial and text seperately not in the same message.

    'grabEmailAddresses()
    'grabTextAddresses()
    Dim subject As String = "Broadcast Alert"
    Dim mClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.aaicorp.com")
    Dim addresses As String
    Dim addresses1 As String

    If emailOrText = "email" Then
        '*******************************************************************************************************************
        'This section addes Bcc to the To: line so there is no one listed in this line and the people do not see all the emil addresses

        'create the mail message
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()

        'set the addresses
        'to specify a friendly 'from' name, we use a different ctor
        mail.From = New MailAddress("flims@aai.textron.com", "FLIMS Site")

        'since the To,Cc, and Bcc accept addresses, we can use the same technique as the From address
        'since the To, Cc, and Bcc properties are collections, to add multiple addreses, we simply call .Add(...) multple times
        'addresses = "spowers@aai.textron.com"
        addresses &= grabEmailAddresses() ' addresses is dimensioned before the if statement The grabEmailAddressed is a function to get the email addresses
        Dim SendBcc As String = (addresses)
        mail.Bcc.Add(SendBcc)

        'Response.Write("<script>alert('" & addresses & "')</script>")
        'Response.Write("<script>alert('" & SendBcc & "')</script>")

        'set the content
        mail.Subject = "Broadcast Alert"

        'set the body 
        mail.Body = message

        'Send the email 
        'mClient.Send(mail) 'mClient is dimensioned before the if statement
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Email Messages Sent')</script>")

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000) ' This is used to have a pause to send out the first message if you send email and text


        '*****************************************************************************************************************************
        'If you want to see all of the sender do this instead uncomment this section and commnet out the above

        ''Response.Write("<script>alert('" & addresses & "')</script>")
        'Dim m = New MailMessage("flims@aai.textron.com", addresses, subject, message)
        'mClient.Send(m)
        'System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000) ' This is used to have a pause to send out the first message if you send email and text
    Else
        addresses1 &= grabTextAddresses() ' addresses is dimensioned before the if statement The grabTextAddressed is a function to get the text phone numbers
        'Response.Write("<script>alert('" & addresses1 & "')</script>")
        'Response.Write("<script>alert('" & message & "')</script>")
        Dim m = New MailMessage("flims@aai.textron.com", addresses1, subject, message)
        'mClient.Send(m) ' mClient is dimensioned befor the if statement and "m" is dimension above
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Text Messages Sent')</script>")
    End If

End Sub

Protected Function grabEmailAddresses() As String

    "code for function"
End Function


Protected Function grabTextAddresses() As String
    "code for function"
End Function
```

I put all of the relevant code in here in case you want to see it, I know it is a lot. The button click is first, and all of the subsequent functions are ran. right now the email/text send (mClient.Send()) is commented out for testing.
Any input about my problem is welcomed, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why this pushes the form to the left, but I changed the position to absolute `position:absolute;` and did `left:25%;` and this centers it. So it's a fix, just not the one I was looking for.